# Limit of a two variable function $\frac{x^2\sin^2{y}}{2x^2+y^2}$

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find the limit as $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$ of $\frac{x^2\sin^2{y}}{2x^2+y^2}$

I tried this:

$\frac{x^2}{2x^2+y^2}<1/2$ so using the squeeze theorem $\frac{x^2}{2x^2+y^2}<1/2 \sin^2{y}$
and the limit of the right handside is 0, so the limit of the function must be 0. But wolfram alpha says the limit doesnt exist. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: "... or cannot be determined". Give it $\frac{x^2y^2}{2x^2+y^2}$ such that it understands it.

Comment: oh so it actually does exist?

Comment: If so this is probably the first time I have been able to solve something that wolfram alpha has not ;)

Comment: You are right and you have obtained the limit correctly. Only note that $\frac{x^2}{2x^2+y^2}\le \frac 12,$ because it is possible $y=0.$ But this doesn't change you conclussion.

Comment: Oh ya, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Since $$2x^2+y^2 \geq 2\sqrt{2}\,|xy|$$
it follows that:
$$\left|\frac{x^2\sin^2 y}{2x^2+y^2}\right|\leq\left|xy\cdot\frac{xy}{2x^2+y^2}\right|\leq\frac{|xy|}{2\sqrt{2}}$$
so the limit is zero.